# How to create many graphs on chart in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function, sparklines

Via  `=SPARKLINE(myFun())` I can draw one graph. However I need to draw 10 graphs.

I tried to return in myFun multi-dimension array, but I got:

> Error
> Function SPARKLINE line parameter 1 range must be a single row, a single column, two rows or two columns.

In Google I found some examples how to create many graphs selecting range manually (for example see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63174/create-a-google-sheets-chart-with-multiple-data-ranges-with-separate-key-columns/63233). But it is not my case. I need to draw data from functions. In sheets I have data which I need to process.

Comment: Can you provide a sanitised copy of the spreadsheet you're working on, including the desired output, as well as the code related to `myFun()`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177545/how-to-create-many-graphs-on-chart-in-google-sheets?noredirect=1#comment113533724_64177846 

The question does not relate to my data. I think this is solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `SPARKLINE` doesn't support array formulas(in the sense of autofill), you would need to use a menu  or a button to create(`setFormulas()`) multiple `=SPARKLINE(MYFUN())` formulas over 10 cells.

Alternatively, You can create full fledged charts using the [`EmbeddedChart`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart) class.

Comment: But I want in one cell in different colors. In 10 cells I can use =SPARKLINE(MYFUN1()), =SPARKLINE(MYFUN2()) and so on.

Comment: @IgorTarasov 1.Edit your question to make that clear.  2. Is that even possible manually? What type of chart are you creating and Does that support multiple colors? Do you have examples of such in the wild?

Comment: for example see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63174/create-a-google-sheets-chart-with-multiple-data-ranges-with-separate-key-columns/63233

I would like to get the same via any function which accept array.

My problem is that my data are not in cells. They are in array which I generate on other data.

Comment: @IgorTarasov Those are not sparklines. They're actual charts. For those charts, your can use `EmbeddedChart` class.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems what I need.